# Struggleing to validate a user entry in tkinter

Tags: validation, tkinter

Here is part of some code i create for a project in tkinter using sqlite3 as a database in python. Im trying to make it so that when a user enters their values into the entry fields it only accepts integer values, and tried to implement this into the validation function. Ive tried using the try and except method, but this still seems to allow all values to be added to the table. How else could i attempt to make this work?

```
     def validation (self):
            try:
                int(self.inc.get()) and int(self.out.get()) == True
            except ValueError:
                self.message['text'] = 'Value must be a number!'



    def adding (self):
        if self.validation:
            query = 'INSERT INTO data VALUES (?,?)'
            parameters = (self.inc.get(), self.out.get())
            self.run_query (query, parameters)
            self.message ['text'] = 'Record [] added' .format (self.inc.get ())
            self.inc.delete (0, END)
            self.out.delete (0, END)
        else:
            self.message['text'] = 'Income or outgoing field is empty'
        self.viewing_records()

    def deleting (self):
        self.message ['text'] = ''
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection ()) ['values'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Please, select record!'
            return

        self.message['text'] = ''
        Income = self.tree.item (self.tree.selection ()) ['text']
        query = 'DELETE FROM data WHERE totalinc = ?'
        self.run_query (query, (Income, ))
        self.message['text'] = 'Record [] deleted.'.format(Income)
        self.viewing_records()

    def editing (self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        try:
            self.tree.item (self.tree.selection ())['values'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Please select record'
            return

        name = self.tree.item (self.tree.selection ())['text']
        old_out = self.tree.item (self.tree.selection ())['values'][0]

        self.edit_wind = Toplevel ()
        self.edit_wind.title ("Editing")

        Label (self.edit_wind, text = 'Old income:').grid (row = 0, column = 1)
        Entry (self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = name), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        Label (self.edit_wind, text = 'New income:').grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        new_inc = Entry (self.edit_wind)
        new_inc.grid (row = 1, column = 2)

        Label (self.edit_wind, text = 'Old outgoing:').grid (row = 2, column = 1)
        Entry (self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = old_out), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 2, column = 2)
        Label (self.edit_wind, text = 'New outgoing: ').grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        new_out = Entry (self.edit_wind)
        new_out.grid (row = 3, column = 2)

        Button (self.edit_wind, text = 'Save changes', command = lambda: self.edit_records (new_inc.get(), name, new_out.get(), old_out)).grid (row = 4, column = 2, sticky = W)

        self.edit_wind.mainloop()

    def edit_records (self, new_inc, name, new_out, old_out):
        query = "UPDATE data SET totalinc = ?, totalout = ? WHERE totalinc = ? AND totalout = ?"
        parameters = (new_inc, new_out, name, old_out)
        self.run_query (query, parameters)
        self.edit_wind.destroy()
        self.message['text'] = 'Record [] changed.' .format (name)
        self.viewing_records()






if __name__ == '__main__':
    wind = Tk()
    application = Product (wind)
    wind.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've posted too much code. Please create a [mcve]. Though, before you do, you should do some research. There are several questions and answers on this site related to entry validation.

Answer (score 2):

```py
str = '8'
if str.isdigit():
    print(str)
```

I suggest taking a look at is isdigit().